# passing value from ng-model to ng-click function

Tags: angularjs

i have `<td>` looking like this:

```
    <td>
        <input type="text"  ng-repeat="letter in letters(cron_format) track by $index" value="{{letter}}" ng-model="letter"/>
        <button class="save" ng-click="saveCron(user_id,script_id,cron_format,letter)">save</button>
    </td>
```

the `value="{{letter}}` and ng-model="letter" both contain the correct value inside but when i pass it to the saveCron() function like this:

```
$scope.saveCron = function(userId,scriptId,cronFormat,data){
    console.log(data);
}
```

i get undefined..why is that?

Comment: are there multiple people working on this project all asking similar questions with identical variable names or are you asking your questions from multiple accounts?  At least a dozen questions in the last 3 days with `letter in letters(cron_format)`

Comment: in fact, I tried to describe in a very similar question a few hours ago that you can't use `ng-repeat` and `ng-model` both on the same element.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why `letter` is undefined is that there is no `letter` in your controller's scope.

Then you may ask, why `<input type="text"  ng-repeat="letter in letters(cron_format) track by $index" value="{{letter}}" ng-model="letter"/>` can work?

It's because `ng-repeat` will create a separate child scope for each element and create an object called `letter` in this scope. Then `ng-model` can read it. However it's not accessible in the parent scope (your controller's scope).

Hope my explanation is clear.